# Safe removal of NT SERVICE\All services from GPO log on as a service

Tags: active-directory, services, group-policy

I've searched for many weeks now if it's safe to remove NTSERVICE\ALL SERVICES right from 'Log on as a service' User right assigment.

Goal here is to increase my GPO's security. I do want to limit to the strict autorized service accounts to log on my servers.
When a GPO containing Log on a service is created, by default NT SERVICE\All service is granted.

Is there any issue with removing this default permission and putting directly my Service accounts identities?

Comment: If you use any group/managed service accounts(MSA/GMSA), they use the `ALL SERVICES` group to log on as a service by default. Be careful about overwriting any existing members, as services like IIS or hyper-v tend to add their stuff to the ALL SERVICES group too.

Comment: Since it is a local SID, I don't understand with all stuff is added to this group. I do belive that it is a quick fix to allow access without restriction.

Comment: It looks like removing `NTSERVICE\ALL SERVICES` from 'Log on as a service' user right assignment is not safe. Every service uses that SID for 'log on as a service' rights'. You would have to add every virtual account (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-service-accounts#virtual-accounts) like `NT Service\Spooler` to that group, which would be a different list per-computer